# connect through vpn client and access the terminal in remote system

Tags: linux, server, terminal, client, vpn

I want to run code on a server(a system with high configuration and GPU). Now, I have got access to the server through VPN. I am using a VPN client and entered the credentials. The VPN client says "connected". how do I get access to the terminal of the server?

Comment: ssh or rdp. What OS on server have you?

Comment: Linux is installed in server